# How does a standing wave decay?

Tags: waves

This question refers to standing waves in general rather than any particular type of standing wave. It may have nodes only at the ends, or it may have multiple nodes. It may be subject to damping, resistance, or absorption, or not. I assume that when the source of vibration or disturbance that causes the standing wave is removed, the standing wave does not instantly pass out of existence. I would like to know the manner in which the standing wave decays. I assume that something happens to it as a function of time. What equations describe the behavior of a standing wave when the energy source that causes it is removed? I am not looking for an answer involving a secondary effect like reverberation, I want to know the fate of the original standing wave itself.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically all energy transporting waves have damping mechanisms either related to the material they are propagating in or to the boundaries. This usually leads to an exponential decay in time of a free standing wave oscillation which could also be expressed as complex eigenfrequencies of the standing waves.

Comment: If there is a standing wave in a medium that provides no damping, say in a "perfect" vacuum (maybe an EM wave?), and it loses no energy to the nodes at the ends, it would just keep "buzzing" forever with no change in the amplitude or wavelength? Is there a more general or idealized answer? In a real situation  does the decay occur to the amplitude, frequency, or both? Which is the case in energy loss to the damping medium, and in the case of energy loss to the boundary nodes? How is the energy lost? By means of traveling waves generated by the decaying standing wave?

Comment: If there were no losses in the medium and at the boundaries, the standing wave would be oscillating forever. In a real situation, you have energy absorption in the propagating material, energy losses due to imperfect reflections at the boundaries and due to dissipative losses in the reflecting medium. In general, this would lead to a decreasing amplitude with time reflecting the energy loss per unit time. There should be no change in frequency.

Comment: Energy is lost to the medium or to the wall by dissipative (friction) processes, or due to transmission of part of the wave into the reflecting walls when the reflection is not perfect which could result in a traveling wave transporting energy away.

Comment: Could I trouble you to provide the equations that describe the decay of a standing wave? I have been unable to find them.

Comment: @john_best - The equation depends on the type of wave and the damping mechanism you are considering. Mathematically, for a standing wave with nodes at $x=0, a$ and given wavevector $K_n=n\pi/a$ and an exponential  damping constant in time $\lambda$ you get a damped standing wave $$\psi=\exp{(-\lambda t)}\sin {(k_n x)}$$

Comment: @john_best - In general, you need the type of wave and damping mechanism to derive the damped wave dispersion equation so that you obtain the complex angular frequency $\omega =\omega_r+i\omega_i$ as a function of $k$. Then $\omega_i$  corresponds to the damping constant in time.

Comment: @john_best - The full damped standing wave looks then like $$\psi=\exp{i(\omega_r+i\omega_i)t}\sin{(k_n x)}$$